# replace componentWillMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the code from https://github.com/Spyna/react-store/blob/master/src/createStore.js

How should I update the code to fit with the deprecated `componentWillMount` lifecycle method?

**CreateStore**

```
const createStore = (WrappedComponent, initialValue) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { storage: { ...initialValue } };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            let store = {
                get: (key) => {
                    return this.state.storage[key];
                },
                set: (key, value) => {
                    const state = this.state.storage;
                    state[key] = value;
                    this.setState(state);
                },
                remove: (key) => {
                    const state = this.state.storage;
                    delete state[key];
                    this.setState(state);
                }
            }

            this.setState({ store });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <StoreContext.Provider value={{ store: this.state.store }}>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </StoreContext.Provider>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**WithStore**

```
const withStore = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <StoreContext.Consumer>
                    {context => <WrappedComponent store={context.store} {...this.props} />}
                </StoreContext.Consumer>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Homepage using withStore**

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getUser().then((user) => {
            this.props.store.set('user', user);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const user = this.props.store.get('user');
        return (
            <View style={styles.home}>
                <Text>{user.firstname}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    home: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
});

export default withStore(Home);
```

Comment: put it in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: of course I tried but `store.get`, `store.set` and `store.remove` are not defined for my consumers if I do that.

Comment: you can put it in the constructor while declaring state

Comment: @Tarun that's the rightful answer + remove the `setState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood, you want to declare a store inside state and manipulate it using some functions defined inside an object. You don't need to have this object inside your state. Instead, you should keep it on the component instance like this:

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { 
                storage: {...initialValue} 
            };
            this.storageHelper = {
                get: (key) => {
                    return this.state.storage[key];
                },
                set: (key, value) => {
                    const state = this.state.storage;
                    state[key] = value;
                    this.setState(state);
                },
                remove: (key) => {
                    const state = this.state.storage;
                    delete state[key];
                    this.setState(state);
                }  
            }
  }
```

Use `this.storageHelper` accordingly.

Comment: @davmich where have i called the `setState` inside the constructor? The functions containing the `setState` calls don't execute inside the constructor so it shouldn't be a problem.